# mailgun posts to django api timeout randomly

Tags: python, django, mailgun

I have a python/django app that accepts post request from MailGun whenever we receive an email.

Somewhat randomly the posts are timing out, sometimes multiple times, and the emails are getting delayed, sometime ten minutes, sometimes up to an hour.

Looking through the ngnix logs just shows 200's and there's no errors. these requests eventually do post, but its becoming quite a troublesome issue!

First one fails:

```
10/19/14 09:10 AM   Will retry in 600 seconds:  Timeout 
   {
    "severity": "temporary", 
    "tags": [], 
    "delivery-status": {
        "retry-seconds": 600, 
        "message": "Timeout", 
        "code": null, 
        "description": "Timeout", 
        "session-seconds": 0.3908820152282715
    }, 
    "envelope": {
        "targets": "https://xxxx.co/emailintake/", 
        "transport": "http", 
        "sender": "xxxx"
    }, 
    "log-level": "warn", 
    "campaigns": [], 
    "reason": "generic", 
    "user-variables": {}, 
    "flags": {
        "is-authenticated": true, 
        "is-system-test": false, 
        "is-test-mode": false
    }, 
    "timestamp": 1413735007.291641, 
    "message": {
        "headers": {
            "to": "xxxx", 
            "message-id": "xxxx", 
            "from": "xxxx", 
            "subject": "Order #xxxx from xxxx"
        }, 
        "attachments": [], 
        "recipients": [
            "xxxx@xxxx.co"
        ], 
        "size": 7538
    }, 
    "recipient": "https://xxxx.co/emailintake/", 
    "event": "failed"
}`

ten minutes later it passes

`10/19/14 09:20 AM  Posted:
{
    "tags": [], 
    "timestamp": 1413735609.686608, 
    "delivery-status": {
        "message": "", 
        "code": 0, 
        "description": null, 
        "session-seconds": 0.39368700981140137
    }, 
    "log-level": "info", 
    "campaigns": [], 
    "user-variables": {}, 
    "flags": {
        "is-authenticated": true, 
        "is-system-test": false, 
        "is-test-mode": false
    }, 
    "envelope": {
        "targets": "https://xxxx.co/emailintake/", 
        "transport": "http", 
        "sender": "xxxx"
    }, 
    "message": {
        "headers": {
            "to": "xxxx@xxxx.com", 
            "message-id": "xxxx", 
            "from": "xxxx@xxxx.com", 
            "subject": "Order #xxxx from xxxx.com"
        }, 
        "attachments": [], 
        "recipients": [
            "xxxx@xxxx.co"
        ], 
        "size": 7538
    }, 
    "recipient": "https://xxxx.co/emailintake/", 
    "event": "delivered"
}
```

Comment: How long has this happened for? Is it possibly something to do with recent instabilities on their side? Check https://mailgun.statuspage.io/for more info

Comment: it started about 4 days ago.  we have built a backup system up on another similar service to see if its an us problem or a them problem.

Comment: update 2, we emailed their support and the problem vanished. we fixed the glitch.

Comment: was it a glitch on ur side or mailgun's?

Comment: well, just a second there @API_sheriff_orlie, they uh, they fixed the glitch. we never heard back from mailgun, it seemed to work itself out naturally. they always like to avoid confrontation whenever possible.

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4eCd6xUSik